# Problem with the proof of Ehrenfest theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, time, differentiation

My quantum mechanics book has this proof of Ehrenfest theorem: let $A$ be an observable and $\hat{A}$ the operator that represents it. Then we have 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle \hat{A}\rangle=\frac{i}{\hbar}\langle [\hat{H},\hat{A}]\rangle+\left\langle \frac{\partial \hat{A}}{\partial t}\right\rangle.$$
The proof is: 
\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}\langle \hat{A}\rangle=&\frac{d}{dt}\langle\Psi| \hat{A}\Psi\rangle=\left\langle \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}|\hat{A}\Psi\right\rangle+\left\langle \Psi|\frac{\partial \hat{A}\Psi}{\partial t}\right\rangle
\\
\overset{!}{=}&\left\langle \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}|\hat{A}\Psi\right\rangle+\left\langle \Psi|\hat{A}\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}\right\rangle+
\left\langle \Psi|\frac{\partial \hat{A}}{\partial t}\hat{\Psi}\right\rangle.\end{align}
I can't understand how to evaluate the term $\frac{\partial \hat{A}\psi}{\partial t}$. $\hat{A}$ is an operator, if we have a multiplicative operator like the potential then the result is trivial and follow from applying the product rule.

**How to extent this product rule like result to a generic operator $\hat{A}$ though?**

Answer (score 2):

Consider a harmonic potential with a constant $K$ which explicitly depends on time:
$$U(t,x) = \frac{K(t)}{2} x^2\:.$$
Next define
$$A(t) := -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + U(t,x)\:.$$
Here the derivative you pointed out gives a contribution.
Another possibility is $m=m(t)$, giving rise to a temporal dependence in the kinetical energy operator which is not multiplicative as you wanted.

Comment: Ok, this is one of the cases in which I have problems What does it mean to take the derivative of the operator $\frac{\partial \hat {A}}{\partial t}$?

Comment: Imagine the operator being a function of time $A: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{L}, t \rightarrow A(t)$, it should be clear what is meant by $A'(t)$? @Rhino

Comment: Allright, it's a function that gives an operator for any value ov $t$, but why $\frac{\partial \hat{A}\Psi}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}\hat{A}+\frac{\partial \hat{A}}{\partial t}\Psi$?

Comment: To compute the derivative of an operator parametrically depending on $t$ you can use the strong or the weak operator topology. Here, the weak one is sufficient.

Comment: Can you write a more explicit answer? I don't know what an operator topology is.

Comment: $A_n \to A$ strongly if $A_nf \to Af$ for all $f$. Similarly $A_n \to A$ weakly if $\langle g, A_nf \rangle \to\langle g,  Af\rangle$ for all $g, f$. Derivatives are defined accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through the proof for the sake of completion.

$$\frac{d\langle A \rangle}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle$$

Applying the product rule gives

$$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\psi|A|\psi\rangle =\frac{d\langle \psi|}{dt}A|\psi \rangle + \langle \psi |\frac{dA}{dt} |\psi \rangle +  \langle \psi| A \frac{d|\psi \rangle}{dt}$$

Now to reveal some more information we look at the time dependent Schrödinger equation,

$$H|\psi \rangle=i\frac{d|\psi\rangle}{dt}$$

We can write the first two terms as:

$$\frac{d\langle \psi|}{dt}A|\psi \rangle + \langle \psi |\frac{dA}{dt} |\psi \rangle = i\langle\psi|HA|\psi\rangle + -i\langle\psi|AH|\psi\rangle$$
$$=i[H,A]$$

Thus we have Erehnfests theorem
$$\frac{d}{dt} \langle A \rangle = i[H,A] + \langle \psi|\frac{dA}{dt}|\psi \rangle$$

Some notes on this which address your concerns:

Within the Schrodinger picture we assume $A \neq A(t)$ i.e. all the time dependence is in the state $|\psi\rangle  = |\psi (t) \rangle$. Meaning the expressions simplifies to just the commutator of the Hamiltonian.

But if we shift to the Heisenberg picture then there is an *explicit* time dependence on the operator. Meaning that the derivative is well defined and thus has to be considered.